# JQuery OnClick Issue with adding a class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Basically I am adding a class of "id" when a `<div>` is clicked. The ID is updated to "active"

http://mpagallery.co.uk/exibitions/future/

If you click on the small image, the builder-gallery-item `<div>` needs to add a `id="active"` to the end.

Here is what I have tried in my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jJgRQ/123/), and have exactly the same code in an external file, but it just won't work.

```
jQuery(function ($) {
  $(document).ready(function ($) {
    $('.builder-gallery-item').on('click', changeClass);
  });
});

function changeClass() {
  $('.builder-gallery-item').removeAttr('id', 'active');
  $(this).attr('id', 'active');
}
```

Comment: You have a document ready inside a document ready. Unnecessary.

Comment: Tip: Manipulate classes, not IDs.

Comment: `.removeAttr()` expects one parameter, which is the attribute you want to remove.

Comment: j08691 - I have removed the document ready now, it still does not work.

Comment: MelanciaUK - I am trying to change the ID as I already have classes there which need to be kept in there

Comment: You can always have many classes set to the same element.

Comment: Basically, I want it to say active, so i can run another jquery to change the text down below.

Comment: The code in this jsFiddle should do the trick: http://jsfiddle.net/MelanciaUK/jJgRQ/129/

Comment: It is not good practice to name your classes the same as attributes, you are confusing when you keep talking about a id and a class and how your class is id.

Comment: @MelanciaUK - Yours kinda works, but not all will have a link, so causes an error when one div doesn't have a link. And for some strange reason, it only works on the div's that don't have links, well it works, but doesn't add the "active" to the class

Comment: @JGallardo - I was trying to get my head around jQuery and didn't realise I could use addClass and removeClass to just remove one element.

Comment: Checking the page you provided the link, it should work. http://jsfiddle.net/MelanciaUK/jJgRQ/132/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for the [addClass](http://api.jquery.com/addclass/) and [removeClass](http://api.jquery.com/removeclass/) methods

After reading your comment, I would strong *encourage* you to use classes rather than IDs, because [HTML Id elements should be unique](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/127178/two-html-elements-with-same-id-attribute-how-bad-is-it-really)

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
       $(".builder-gallery-item").on("click", function () {
          $('.builder-gallery-item').removeClass('active');
          $(this).addClass('active');
        });
    });
```

See this [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/imoshtokill/4dx2jz5n/)

**Edit** To clean up the comments, the OP has an updated [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jJgRQ/135/), where the active class is still not being applied to the divs that contain pictures.

Based on that JsFiddle, you are calling `addClass('active')` on all of the elements with  the `builder-gallery-item` class rather than just the one that was clicked.  You should be using:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $(".builder-gallery-image").on("click", function () {
        $('.builder-gallery-item').removeClass('active');
        $(this).closest('div').addClass('active');
    });
});
```

`$(this)` was actually referencing the figure object, which is why I used the `$(this).closest('div')` instead.  See the [Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/imoshtokill/jJgRQ/136/)